# How to change the marking threshold K of TCP ECN in mininet

Tags: python, mininet

I want to reproduce the following mininet experiment
[mininet-test](https://github.com/mininet/mininet-tests/tree/master/dctcp)

and i now want to change the marking threshold K of TCP-ECN to test how the value K will affect the result of the simulation.

But i don't know where can i change this value K in the source code because it seem not defined. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Value K is configured as a special case of a `red qdisc`.

This [post](https://reproducingnetworkresearch.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/dctcp-and-queues/) and its [code](https://bitbucket.org/kunyi731/cs244pa2/src/9f9140ddaa5beda93a02270d460ec4093ef6b021/startopo.py?at=final&fileviewer=file-view-default#startopo.py-84) show exmples (notice the options of `enable_red` and `red_params`).